# What does this subtract_gaussian_blur function that uses the GaussianBlur function in OpenCV do?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I came across [this](https://www.kaggle.com/orkatz2/diabetic-retinopathy-preprocess/comments) Kaggle kernel that has the following function.

```
def subtract_gaussian_blur(img):
    gb_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (0, 0), 5)
    return cv2.addWeighted(img, 4, gb_img, -4, 128)
```

That converts this RGB image.

[image]

Into the following image.

[image]

I can see the effect is that it somewhat sharpens the image and turns it into a more grayscale image (not actually grayscale since the image is still RGB) but I'm not actually sure I fully understand what is happening in the function even after reading the OpenCV docs on GaussianBlur and addWeighted.

Also, does this particular image transformation have a specific name that I can do further reading into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main step I can see is `cv2.addWeighted(img, 4, gb_img, -4, 128)`. The underlying equation for addWeighted is `dst(I)=saturate(src1(I)∗alpha+src2(I)∗beta+gamma)`. In the example here, alpha is 4, beta -4, and gamma 128.

My understanding of how that works is it first performs a gaussian blur to make a denoised version of the image. However as well as removing noise, Gaussian Blurring can also "smear" edges, which is important later. It then subtracts the denoised version from the original, and adds 128 to each pixel colour channel.

In regions where the original pixel is identical to the filtered pixel, this will result in a uniform grey region. In areas where the original and filtered pixels differ a lot, you will end up either with a lighter or darker region depending on whether the intensity of the original or filtered pixel is higher. The differences will be most pronounced around edges in the original image, because those will be strongly "smeared" by the gaussian blur.

The result isn't fully greyscale as `addWeighted()` is applied to each colour channel of the pixels separately. Areas where the RGB values of the pre and post blur images differ in an unbalanced way (ie the difference between the two red channels is much bigger than between the blue or green channels) there will be a degree of colour rather than just grey.

Comment: This was such a good and easily understood answer :) Thank you.

Comment: Nice explanation! Regarding names: this function subtracts the mean, but locally computed. It is also a rough approximation to the Lapacian of Gaussian (LoG operator) or the difference of Gaussians (DoG operator).